# Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

### I have configured it like this.why do i report the above error?

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
logging.level.org.springframework.data=DEBUG
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.namingstrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo in your configuration

The correct one should be

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```